# How to load .dta (preserving labels) most comfortable in R?

Tags: r, read-data, r-haven

I work with .dta files and try to make loading data as comfortable as possible. In my view, I need a combination of `haven` and `readstata13`.

- `haven` looks perfect. It provides best "sub-labels". But it does not provide a column-selector-function. I cannot use `read_dta` for large files ( ~ 1 GB / on 64 GB RAM, Intel Xeon E5).
  [image]
  **Question**: Is there a way to select/load a subset of data?
- `read.dta13` is my best workaround. It has `select.cols`. But I have to get `attr` later, save and merge them (for about 10 files).

  **Question**: How can I manually add these second labels which the `haven` package creates? (How are they called?)

[image]

Here is the MWE:

```
library(foreign)
write.dta(mtcars, "mtcars.dta")

library(haven)
mtcars <- read_dta("mtcars.dta")

library(readstata13)
mtcars2 <- read.dta13("mtcars.dta", convert.factors = FALSE, select.cols=(c("mpg", "cyl", "vs")))
var.labels <- attr(mtcars2,"var.labels")
data.key.mtcars2 <- data.frame(var.name=names(mtcars2),var.labels)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`haven`'s [development version](https://github.com/tidyverse/haven) supports selecting columns with the `col_select` argument:

```r
library(haven) # devtools::install_github("tidyverse/haven")
mtcars <- read_dta("mtcars.dta", col_select = c(mpg, cyl, vs))
```

Alternatively; the column labels in RStudio's viewer are taken from the data frame's columns' `"label"` attribute. You can use a simple loop to assign them from the labels read by `readstata13`:

```
for (i in seq_along(mtcars2)) {
  attr(mtcars2[[i]], "label") <- var.labels[i]
}

View(mtcars2)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the development. The `col_select` feature makes `haven` perfect, no more reason to use other packages. But the install of dev version didn't work for me, it says "Error: Failed to install 'haven' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘XX/haven_2.1.1.9000.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status"

Comment: Ok, I had to delete a `00LOCK-haven` folder in my lib manually. Then it worked. Looking foward to the new release of haven.